# Reorder associative array after removing one element

Tags: php, associative-array

I have a 2D associative array which goes something like this:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [foo]=>bar
    [foo]=>bar
    [foo]=>bar
)

[1] => Array
(
    [foo]=>bar
    [foo]=>bar
    [foo]=>bar
)


[2] => Array
(
    [foo]=>bar
    [foo]=>bar
    [foo]=>bar
)
```

I want to be able to remove one element, e.g. [0] and then "refresh" the remaining elements ID's, so [1] and its contents would become the new [0], [2] would become [1] etc.

Comment: You can simply unset a key with `unset($array[0])`, but why is it important that the keys shift up as well?

Comment: `array_values()` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Say you have these array values in $data.
Then you removed the element

ex: `unset($data[0]);`

Now $data will have

```
[1] => Array
(
    [foo]=>bar
    [foo]=>bar
    [foo]=>bar
)


[2] => Array
(
    [foo]=>bar
    [foo]=>bar
    [foo]=>bar
)
```

Now use the function [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$data = array_values($data);
```

Now the associative array is reordered to

```
[0] => Array
(
    [foo]=>bar
    [foo]=>bar
    [foo]=>bar
)

[1] => Array
(
    [foo]=>bar
    [foo]=>bar
    [foo]=>bar
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose

```
$arr = array(0=>array('a','b','c'),1=>array('a','b','c'),2=>array('a','b','c'));
```

Then to get your requirement the steps are :

```
unset($arr[0]);
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)**:

```
$x = [
    ['foo1'=>'bar', 'foo2'=>'bar', 'foo3'=>'bar'],
    ['foo1'=>'bar', 'foo3'=>'bar', 'foo5'=>'bar'],
    ['foo1'=>'bar', 'foo3'=>'bar', 'foo5'=>'bar']];

unset($x[0]);
$x = array_values($x);
print_r($x);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [foo1] => bar
            [foo3] => bar
            [foo5] => bar
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [foo1] => bar
            [foo3] => bar
            [foo5] => bar
        )

)
```